# Is it possible to do this with css? Images shown

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a border-right on my navbar list which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15sEy.png)

However I would like it to look [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3RVS.png) Is this possible without using images instead?

Thanks.

Navbar css

```
.navbar .navbar-inner {
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar .nav {
    margin: 0;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar .nav li {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 11.1%;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    left: 4px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 15px;
}

.navbar .nav li a {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    height: 10px;
    line-height: 10px;
}

#active-link {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.navbar .nav li:first-child a {
    border-left: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.navbar .nav li:last-child a {
    border-right: 0;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
```

Comment: yes sure it is why should it not be? It is very rare that you will need images nowadays for (basic) styling. Look at the pseudo elements (:before/:after) for the "|" if this is your concern.

Comment: Ah yes this seems the easiest solution. I have done 

.navbar .nav li a::after {
    content: "\00a0 " " | ";
}

But there isn't enough whitespace before the vertical bar, ideally I would like it in the middle of two list items, do you know a way I can move it more efficiently ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the border-right to the `<a>` element instead of the `<li>` element.

**Edit 1**

Since your border-right is attached to your a element try this:

.nav li { height: 15px; }
.nav li a { height: 10px; }

You can now probably see that the border is smaller than the menu button itself. Just play a little with the heights to see what you want.

**Edit 2**

Also add this:

```
.nav li a { line-height: 15px; }
```

**The line-height has to be the same height as the list item.**

Comment: It had the same efffect

Comment: Try to set the height of the `<li>`to 15 px and the `<a>` to 10px then it will probably work. .nav li { height: 15px;} .nav li a { height: 10px;} Then just change the li height to whichever height you want and change the a height to how heigh you want your text and border right to be

Comment: Ah yes this works but the border isn't centered, it just goes from the middle to the top

Comment: Still not working, not sure if Im doing it correctly. I've updated my original question with my nav styling.

Comment: The line-height you put in you .nav li a needs to be the same height as the .nav li. So the same height as the list item. Which is 15px;

Answer (score 0):

you may use a pseudo with a border or a single letter

```css
ul {
  background:#EBEBEB;
}
li {
  display:inline-block;
  line-height:3em;
 
  vertical-align:middle;
}
li + li:before {/* do not on first */
  content: ' | ';
  font-size:0.75em;/* resize it here */
  padding:0 1em; 
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #555;/* or box-shadow or border-style if border used*/
  vertical-align:bottom;/* or else */
}
a {
  color:#222;
}
a:hover , a.active{
  color:#FB853C;
```

```html
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="active">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```